# Adding a form to Gatsby JS, with an existing template that is export default

Tags: reactjs, forms, gatsby

I am attempting to follow [this tutorial](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/adding-forms/) to add a form to Gatsby JS. I understand it if my file wasn't setup differently. Firstly the tutorials component starts like this

```
export default class IndexPage extends React.Component {
```

Where I have this

```
export default ({ data }) => (
```

Then I am asked to place the following inside of it. I tried with both the render and return portion, and without.

```
state = {
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
  }
  handleInputChange = event => {
    const target = event.target
    const value = target.value
    const name = target.name
    this.setState({
      [name]: value,
    })
  }
  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    alert(`Welcome ${this.state.firstName} ${this.state.lastName}!`)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          First name
          <input
            type="text"
            name="firstName"
            value={this.state.firstName}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          />
        </label>
        <label>
          Last name
          <input
            type="text"
            name="lastName"
            value={this.state.lastName}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          />
        </label>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    )
  }
```

Here is all my code without the render and return portion

```
import React from 'react'
import { HelmetDatoCms } from 'gatsby-source-datocms'
import { graphql } from 'gatsby'
import Layout from "../components/layout"



export default ({ data }) => (





  <Layout>

  state = {
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
  }
  handleInputChange = event => {
    const target = event.target
    const value = target.value
    const name = target.name
    this.setState({
      [name]: value,
    })
  }
  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    alert(`Welcome ${this.state.firstName} ${this.state.lastName}!`)
  }
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <label>
        First name
        <input
          type="text"
          name="firstName"
          value={this.state.firstName}
          onChange={this.handleInputChange}
        />
      </label>
      <label>
        Last name
        <input
          type="text"
          name="lastName"
          value={this.state.lastName}
          onChange={this.handleInputChange}
        />
      </label>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>


    <article className="sheet">
      <HelmetDatoCms seo={data.datoCmsPricing.seoMetaTags} />

        <section className="left-package-details">
          <h1 className="sheet__title">{data.datoCmsPricing.title}</h1>
          <p>
            <span>${data.datoCmsPricing.priceAmount}</span> | <span>{data.datoCmsPricing.lengthOfSession}</span>
          </p>

          {data.datoCmsPricing.details.map(detailEntry => { return <li key={detailEntry.id}> {detailEntry.task}</li>})}

          <p>
            {data.datoCmsPricing.numberOfSessions}
          </p>
          <a href="#">book</a>
          <p>{data.datoCmsPricing.minimumMessage}</p>
        </section>

        <section className="right-package-details">

            <img src={data.datoCmsPricing.coverImage.url} />
            <div
              className=""
              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                __html: data.datoCmsPricing.descriptionNode.childMarkdownRemark.html,
              }}
            />


        </section>

    </article>
  </Layout>
)

export const query = graphql`
  query WorkQuery($slug: String!) {
    datoCmsPricing(slug: { eq: $slug }) {
      seoMetaTags {
        ...GatsbyDatoCmsSeoMetaTags
      }
      title
      priceAmount
      details{
        task
      }
      lengthOfSession
      numberOfSessions
      minimumMessage
      descriptionNode {
        childMarkdownRemark {
          html
        }
      }
      coverImage {
        url
      }
    }
  }
`
```

and the error I get is

```
There was a problem parsing "/mnt/c/Users/Anders/sites/jlfit-cms/src/templates/pricingDetails.js"; any GraphQL
fragments or queries in this file were not processed.

This may indicate a syntax error in the code, or it may be a file type
that Gatsby does not know how to parse.

File: /mnt/c/Users/Anders/sites/jlfit-cms/src/templates/pricingDetails.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is because you are trying to use state (and `setState`) on a functional component when the example uses a class.

Functional components don't have the same tools/syntax/APIs available to you as a class component (for better or worse) so you have to ensure you're using the correct approach for each case.

In the most recent versions of React you can have the equivalent of `state` and `setState` made available to you by using [React hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html), more specifically the `useState` hook.

I've put together a quick working example of the code you pasted in your question converted to React hooks. You can find it on [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/example-form-using-hooks-ctonj).

I recommend you have a read over the initial parts of the React docs to ensure you're familiar with the foundational concepts or React, it will save a lot of headache in the future.